# Is there a way to provide a score as to how reliable the value of the row based on list is associated with the group ID?

Tags: r, fuzzy

I have a dataset that looks like this. Trying to do something within the same idea as this image from

https://www.placekey.io/blog/fuzzy-logic-address-matching

[image]

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Date = c("2020-01- 
\n04", 
"2020-04-03", "2020-12-10", "2020-09-12", "2020-11-19", "2020-04- \n03", 
"2020-06-03", "2020-05-03", "2020-08-09", "2020-10-10"), Name = c("Jon", 
"Mike", "", "Rodney", "Jon", "Mike", "", "Ryan", "Ryan", "Ryan"
), Phone = c("555-555-5555", "123-456-7890", "123-456-7890", 
"333-333-3333", "", "123-456-7890", "098-765-4321", "", "", "444-444- 
\n4444"
), Email = c("Jon@gmail.com", "Mike@gmail.com", "Mike@gmail.com", 
"Rodney@gmail.com", "", "", "", "Ryan@gmail.com", "", "Ryan2@gmail.com"
), Address = c("123 Main Street", "456 Washingto Avenue", "", 
"16 Henderson St", "", "456 Washingto Avenue", "123 Lincoln Avenue", 
"123 Lincoln Avenue", "", "156 Jefferson Street"), Group = c("1", 
"2", "2", "3", "1", "2", "4", "4", "4", "5")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want it to eventually look like this

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Date = c("2020-01- 
04", "2020-04-03", "2020-12-10", "2020-09-12", "2020-11-19", "2020-04- 
03", "2020-06-03", "2020-05-03", "2020-08-09", "2020-10-10"), Name = 
c("Jon", "Mike", "", "Rodney", "Jon", "Mike", "", "Ryan", "Ryan", "Ryan"
), Phone = c("555-555-5555", "123-456-7890", "123-456-7890", 
"333-333-3333", "", "123-456-7890", "098-765-4321", "", "", "444-444- 
4444"), Email = c("Jon@gmail.com", "Mike@gmail.com", "Mike@gmail.com", 
"Rodney@gmail.com", "", "", "", "Ryan@gmail.com", "Ryan@gmail.com", 
"Ryan2@gmail.com"), Address = c("123 Main Street", "456 Washingto 
Avenue","", "16 Henderson St", "", "456 Washingto Avenue", "123 Lincoln 
Avenue", 
"123 Lincoln Avenue", "", "156 Jefferson Street"), Group = c("1", 
"2", "2", "3", "1", "2", "4", "4", "4", "5"), Score = c("1", 
"1", ".88", "1", ".96", ".96", "1", "1", ".25", "1")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Note that the dataset groups the entries based on similarities.

```
 Col<-("Name","Phone","Email","Address")
```

I would like to arbitrarily set a score within the row relative group as to how reliable the group id is associated with the row. The more columns filled and correspond to the prototype(all columns filled) the higher the score. Three overlapping columns is better than two.

Comment: This doesn't suggest the need for "fuzzy", since either `Phone` or `Email` can be used as an authoritative column for inference. That is, `ave(dat$Name, dat$Phone, FUN = function(z) replace(z, !nzchar(z), z[nzchar(z)][1]))` will work (using just `Phone`), and there are likely very readable dplyr-pipes that do the same.

Comment: Please don't open a new question every time you have an addition or edit to an unclosed question. Just [edit] the question and add it. While the Stack interface does not firmly prevent you from doing it, it is likely that some users will notice it and possibly react negatively (or at least just ignore your questions altogether).

Comment: The problem when i do that is it's not seen as much. Another thought was deleting a previous question, but i don't want to discredit the help. Maybe i'm mistaken but that's the way it seems.

Comment: I don't know how re-asking the same question for the purpose of keeping it high on the list of recent questions is anything other than manipulative. I understand that you want a solution to your problem and getting more people to see it is the way to make that happen, but in so doing you are pushing another question off of the recent-list more quickly than what would normally have happened, valuing your question as more important than theirs. Honestly, I don't know the best way to do this without community impact, it's a general flaw of the current setup.

Comment: Good to know. However this question is slightly different than the follow up I asked. Here I don't look to get a score value. There is a purpose of both scenarios in different situations.

Comment: I noticed that and inferred it was a refinement, not a significant change. Is it still distinct-enough in your mind that you think it should be two open questions?

Comment: I'll modify this one to resemble the second one.

Comment: But if it resembles the other one, there will be no real difference. If the other is adequately answered for you, does it not solve both of the issues?

Comment: The other one is not solved. I want to get a score for the match not just approximation.